# Is it bad to use globals in a low power multicore microcontroller? (C++)

Tags: c++, global-variables, microcontroller, multicore

I have a Parallax Propeller, which is an 8-core microcontroller, clocked at 80MHz (i.e. its a lot better than an Arduino but not amazing).

I have a few variables I need access to throughout my code - pitch and roll angles, and so on (all floats). My intention is to declare them as extern volatiles - globals that will *only* be set inside a class, and *only* read elsewhere (the volatile is there as it is multicore)(extern as the class is in a separate file).

Is this bad practise? I am trying to avoid calling them up using functions, as that will only slow things down - all variables are stored in main ram, so it shouldn't matter how they are placed there. Is there a better way to do this?

Assuming it was better to call them up using functions, how would this be done?

Comment: `volatile` does not help you with threading & caching issues unless the platform explicitly provides guarantees. Use `volatile` for single-threaded access of memory mapped thingies. For anything else, treat as poison.

Comment: Can you explain that further? I was under the impression that `volatile` forces the code to check ram for the variable, rather than allowing the compiler to optimize it - that if using multicore, assuming all variables are stored in the same ram (which they will be), that it would retrieve the correct value?

Comment: The `volatile` keyword won't necessarily prevent race conditions on a multicore. If you are running several threads I think you are going to have to synchronize your variable access.

Comment: Maybe this one will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131858/c-program-with-minimum-ram

Comment: @Galik I am aware of the race condition issue. I think. the variables are only ever written to in one place, only only read elsewhere - and when being read, it will always be the most up to date data that is desired - i.e. if i don't read the global before it gets updated, that's perfectly OK. I will only ever want the most up to date info

Comment: @Mauvai  Don't forget that your processor may use a memory cache.  Also, volatile doesn't ensure atomicity:  what if the reader reads in same time than the solo writer ? With volatile it could be that you read a value which is only partially updated (f.ex: the first byte of an int correspnds to the new value, but the remaining ones still contain the old value to be replaced).

Answer (score 2):

`volatile` guarantees that the compiler doesn't "optimise away accesses to a variable" (the classic example is:

```
 bool b = false;

 while(!b) /* do nothing */;
```

which the compiler turns to:

```
 bool b = false;

 bool tmp = !b;         // tmp is really a processor register.
 while(tmp) /* do nothing */;
```

Since nothing in the loop is changing `b`, it's a valid optimisation for the compiler to do this.

Using `volatile bool b;` will guarantee that every time you "use" `b` in your code, the compiler reads/writes the actual variable, rather than some "temporary copy".

However, `volatile` does not guarantee:

1. That the data is updated atomically - in other words, if you store something, half the new data may be stored, while another half is the old value, causing all kinds of "interesting" results [such as random values in a `float`].
2. That the other cpu's caches are aware that the value has changed - in other words, the value read by one CPU may have been updated some time ago on aother CPU - say `b` in the above code - despit `volatile`, the CPU may well not have caused a flush on another CPU's caches.

You need to take care of caches and atomic updates to ensure that ytou don't get "fun" bugs caused by either of those not being done correctly. This of course applies regardless of whether you use global variables or otherwise share data between processors - the only case where you can rely on it is when you have a proper interface via the OS or runtime environment, which provides guarantees for these things.

Comment: Assuming all these variables are stored in shared RAM (i.e. the core ram doesn't store variables (i think)), should these problems be non issues? Im reasonably sure access to the ram is managed to prevent simultaneous read/writes (remember too that this is a microcontroller, not a full pc or SBC like a raspberry Pi)

Comment: Does the CPU cores have caches? Are float values stored in one cycle? I don't know this particular architecture, but in general, these are problems you have to care about (and they are often "mysterious" to debug, because when you add code to debug, such as a printf, or write to an LED or something, the problem moves/changes/disappears).

Comment: Yeah iv had problems like that before with LabVIEW. painful. there is 32KB main RAM, and each core has 2KB of its own ram - but as far as i am aware, variables are stored in main ram, unless the entire c file will fit in the core ram

Answer (score 1):

For the topical question: No, it is not necessarily bad to use global variables in a microcontroller. Whether the Propeller is "low power" is arguable, but if I recall correctly it has neither floating point nor functionality to do multiword atomic access, by design. Any core in it has 1/8th of the main memory access cycles, whether it wants them or not.

You describe storing attitude in a set of global variables. If every word may be independently updated and is written in one atomic operation (I believe the propeller has 32 bit RAM as well as processors), you can get away with ignoring synchronisation, but if there's ever a requirement to correlate the measurements you want to use some sort of barrier or lock. The Propeller was designed to operate without locks by having predictable timing, but that's basically only for cycle counting assembly programmers; it won't help you with C++ at all.

The Propeller does have [hardware locks](https://sites.google.com/site/propellergcc/documentation/libraries/propeller-h-library#TOC-lockclr), implemented through a pointlessly awkward and limited set of test-and-set primitives. If you manage to make sense of the [Spin documentation](https://lamestation.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SPIN/LOCKSET) for them you could use them (because neither the datasheet nor the GCC documentation covers their semantics).

As for this controller being "a lot better" than the Arduino? I wouldn't say that's a given. It has only primitive timer and video generation peripherals (anything else is done in software), the processors take four cycles per instruction compared to the AVR's typical one or two, and you could just as easily have gotten a Cortex M4F based microcontroller which do have floating point.

Comment: Given that I'm still a student, the prop seemed like a better option. Is the M4F capable of pwm, i2c, spi, and all that stuff? Is there an useable support forum where im not going to get lambasted for being a complete noob?

Comment: M4F based chips do tend to have all those functions; the Propeller oddly doesn't, aside from the PWM. As a beginner the actual performance and efficiency of the chip will be much less significant than the community and tools, and I'm unfamiliar with how much Propeller has grown in that regard; they have the backing of the Basic Stamp people. For ARM based controllers the primary platform is called mbed. IMHO, Propeller dropped important functions (interrupts) in favour of tricky functionality (threading) whilst not assisting that model (f.e. using channels and selection wait). XMOS is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem inherits from the multithread application, namely two or more threads can access (read or write) one variable parallel. In that cases the **synchronisation** is one of the most important aspect. It is all same which technique you use (locking, atomic operation, semaphores etc.) you have avoid it inconsistency of the variable (i.e. during a reading operation an other thread writes the variable).

So, if you use external global variable all the external modules can access this variable directly **without synchronisation**. Certainly the developer implementing the specified module can use atomic operation (or other solution), but it depends on his or her attention, and **the responsibility of synchronisation goes to all the external modules accessing the global variable** which is a bad methodology and (if it is possible) you have to avoid.

As solution in case of the most multithread system **all the methods which can access a variable directly have to be implemented in the same module**. The benefits of this solution:

- The methods can uses the common synchronisation solution therefore the parallel and synchronised access of the variable is solved.
- Generally one module is implemented by one developer therefore the synchronisation mistakes are also reduced.
- The other modules (and the other developer) will get a well-specified and synchronized interface to access the common resources (global variables).

So, the external modules can access these global variables only by means of interface methods. Certainly in this case some insignificant calling overhead will appear, but if you would like to avoid it and make your code more efficient you can declare these interface methods as **inline methods**.

Answer (score 0):

the gcc or C impementation on the propeller is a hack at best the multicore features and stuff are tossed out to make C available.  so while it is one thing to say the C standard this or that or the religious debates over globals or not are one thing, but then there is the implementation of C on that platform which may or may not really conform to any said standards.

I agree with another person the propeller if used as designed has some features that are interesting, but an arduino is much cleaner, pretty much anything is.  If you actually want hardware multithreading go with XMOS, it has their own C implementation for their features, very cool hardware as in style/design, but not cool as in power consumption.  The propeller is a neat toy if you toss the C and use it as it was designed, once you go with C you are crippling it and turning it into a very weak microcontroller, pretty much every other competitor is better at that point.  I was extremely disappointed when I finally bought one and looked behind the curtain.

Unless their is an implementation problem, it is okay to use globals and use volatile on those to get code to share that global.  May leave a bad taste in some folks mouths, but per spec it should work.